# Android Fabric TwitterCore login without TwitterLoginButton

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

According to [the TwitterCore documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login) :

> The simplest way to authenticate a user is using TwitterLoginButton.

How do you authenticate a user **without** the TwitterLoginButton?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at `TwitterAuthClient`.

An example usage would be something like (where getCallingActivity() can be replaced with your calling `Activity`),

```
TwitterAuthClient twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
twitterAuthClient.authorize(getCallingActivity(), new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(final Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            final TwitterSession sessionData = result.data;
            // Do something with the returned TwitterSession (contains the user token and secret)

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(final TwitterException e) {
            // Do something on fail
        }
    });
```

Then delegate the onActivityResult to `TwitterAuthClient`,

```
twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: You don't need to create a button for this. Please see my answer.

Comment: @AndrewSmiley Yes, my answer does not need a button (TwitterLoginButton). In this case, one just needs to put this snippet inside the event where he wants to. :D

Comment: Good call! Also, didn't realize how similar our answers were until I posted mine! :/

Comment: Oh there it is, I was looking for your answer, now I see it, and yes, they're actually the same. :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a button for this. Basically, if you dig into some of the classes, you'll find that the code is relatively straightforward. So, here's how I did it. You just need to call `TwitterAuthClient().authorize(Activity, Callback<TwitterSession)`

The full code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;


/**
 * Created by Andrew on 6/23/15.
 */
public class ConnectTwitterActivity extends Activity {
    //The auth client itself
    /*you can abstract this and call TwitterCore.getInstance().login()
    but basically that call is doing this one.. 
    */
    TwitterAuthClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //instanciate our client
        client = new TwitterAuthClient();
        //make the call to login 
        client.authorize(this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                //feedback
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                //feedback
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //this method call is necessary to get our callback to get called. 
        client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This code works in a live application that's available in the Android market....

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to call the regular Twitter [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview) mechanism through something like Twitter4J. If you use the TwitterLoginButton this is all wrapped up for you via functions in Twitter Kit.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to not add a TwitterLoginButton in your layout(s), create a TwitterLoginButton programmatically and manually perform a click event:

```
TwitterLoginButton button = new TwitterLoginButton(this);

button.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        // Do something on failure
    }
});

button.performClick();
```

The key point here being that once you create this button, you can call `button.performClick()` at your convenience.

Comment: Thanks, that was the obvious solution.  The documentation implies that there is another way that doesn't use the LoginButton, but maybe not.

Comment: There is TwitterCore.getInstance().logIn(getActivity(), twitterCallback), but there is a bug where if you cancel out of it the Twitter client doesn't receive the the onActivityResult, so I had to programmatically create a button and call performClick anyway

Comment: You don't need to create a button for this. Please see my answer.